# how to install simulator 7.0 in Xcode 5.0.2

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, titanium-alloy

Am completely new to Mac and infact this is my first use of Apple system, am using titanium appcelerator to build my app. I installed Xcode 5.0.2 which comes with iOS 7.0.3 simulator. But appcelerator 3.1.3.GA sdk supports upto 7.0 simulator. So is there a way to downgrade simulator to 7.0 version?  and as I build my app completely with 3.1.3.GA sdk am not interested in again building with 3.2.0.GA sdk, because of some errors. So please help me downgrade simulator to 7.0 version if possible. Thank you.

Comment: May be you should use lower version of XCode.

Comment: Get the Xcode 5.0 it have ios 7.0 simulator

Comment: Thank you Armaan and Retro, I will download Xcode 5.0 and test app.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that you need to run in the lower versions as well, but you have been created a App `with the newer architecture of XCODE` . If so, then you need to `change the architecture as in build settings`:
[image]

and also `check deployment target`:
[image]

Comment: Thank you Kumar, where this option lies in Xcode? and Actually am not using Xcode to develop am using Titanium Studio(an IDE used to develop apps by Appcelerators). I need iOS 7 simulator, is it possible to configure with 5.0.2 Xcode itself.

Comment: In the  project target.